# iOS Calendar is stuck

Tags: iphone, calendar

One of my calendars is stuck on my iPhone. I tried to double-click the home button, but the Calendar app is not one of the icons showing in the task bar, so I can't close it manually. Can you assist?

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"?

Comment: One point to note, you can't kill the app you're currently in.  You have to return to the home screen before bringing up the task bar, then you can kill the app.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the phone.  This will close all apps.

Hold the lock button (on top of the phone) for 4 seconds, then swipe the red bar to turn it off.  When the spinning icon disappears, hold the lock button for 1 second, and an Apple logo will appear.  Try using your calendar again.